# steps to connect database

Tags: iphone

How can I connect to an SQLite database and what are the steps for connecting. I knew some information i.e open mozilla firefox and go to tools select add-ons. What is next process?

Comment: 1. Open Mozilla Firefox. 2. Navigate to 'google.com'. 3. Search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- firstly you should download the sqlite manager addons with your firefox browser
- goto tools > sqlite manager
- your sqlit page will open, firstly create database select store location specially in project folder, than you can create table, the rows & column and you can enter data into it.

Comment: [Here is where you can find the SQLite Manager add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).